# SSAS Cube Measure fact table error

Tags: ssis, ssas, ssas-2008

I have a SSAS Cube with dimensions and measure/facts tables.
I'm not able to add any string data type columns to measure group while creating cube. 
I get below error.
"Errors in the metadata manager. The data type of the 'Loan Type' measure is not valid because the data type of the measure is a string type."

I did double check the data type for my column and it's varchar() on database and wchar in SSAS cube. I have changed the data type to Inherited and it still doesn't work.
Not sure what to do.

Question: Can i add string/varchar data type to measure group in cube. I know measures are usually Int/double/date columns. Is there a possibility, Let me know also the error.

Thanks!!

Comment: why tag `informatica` ? its MSBI right?  and you could always convert varchar to int (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977911/sql-server-converting-varchar-to-int)

Comment: Thanks for response. I shouldn't have added informatica but your answer doesn't make any sense. Does it work if i change to int because  actual column in database is varchar or string.

Comment: Measures in SSAS are typically aggregated with a sum/count/etc. You can aggregate something and then format it. Can you explain what you are doing with loan type string in relation to a measure?

Comment: I'm trying to do a drill thru information so that Business users can see more information when they drill through and loan_type is one of the string data type columns.

Comment: 'Loan Type' should be an attribute in a dimension, not a measure.

Answer (score 2):

Loan type should be an attribute of a dimension rather than a measure. SSAS works best with a [dimensional model](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1304071).

If you need to make a [drill though action](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166579.aspx), there is built-in functionality for that in SSAS which allows you to choose which dimension attributes should be included). If you move to Tabular SSAS, you can use [BIDS Helper](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/releases/view/114725) to help you build the drill through.

Answer (score 0):

"Measures are the bits of **numerical data** that we need to aggregate." (Delivering Business Intelligence with Microsoft SQL Server 2012, Third Edition, by Brian Larson).

You mentioned that "measures are usually Int/double/date columns." Have you tried using numerical values for your measures? Then you could use string data types for your dimensions if needed.